# How to insert a div before another div?

Tags: javascript, dojo

This my HTML code:

```
<div id="contextToolBar" class="dijitToolbar xwtContextualToolbar" wairole="menubar" role="menubar" widgetid="contextToolBar">

<table class="xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainer" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" dojoattachpoint="_contextualToolbarTable">

<tbody class="xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTB">
<tr class="xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTR">
<td> </td>

<td class="xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTD" vertical-align="top" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"> </td>

<td vertical-align="top">
***<div class="xwtQuickFilter" dojoattachpoint="quickFilterNode">***
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I want to add another div before  and I am doing following in my JS:

```
var flagId =dojo.query("#contextToolBar .xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainer .xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTB .xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTB .xwtQuickFilter");

var n = dojo.create("div",  {
    id: "informationDialog", 
    dojoType: "dijit.form.Button", 
    iconClass: "xwtContextualIcon xwtContextualAddRow", 
    showLabel: "false", 
    onclick: "return showClusterInstallationDialog();"
}, flagId, "first");
```

But I am getting a `TypeError: doc is undefined`. I think I am not getting a `flagId` properly. What have I done wrong?

I then tried to use `domConstruct.create` instead of `dojo.create` as well, but it gave me error as `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dojo.query` returns a `NodeList`, so when using that to try to add a new div, you get the exception that you see.

```
var node;
dojo.query(
    "#contextToolBar .xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainer .xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTB .xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTB .xwtQuickFilter")
    .forEach(function(n) { node = n; });
```

If you want to add the new node before the `node`, then use `before`, not `first`. `first` will add it to the child collection as the first element.

```
var newnode = dojo.create('div, {}, node, 'before');
```

Comment: I did the changes as suggested by you. The page loaded without any error , but the new div element didn't get inserted.

Comment: I think your query is incorrect.  You have .xwtContextualToolbarRibbonContainerTB twice.  Did you test to see what comes back from the query?

Comment: I even tried this , dojo.query(
    ".xwtQuickFilter")
    .forEach(function(n) { node = n; });

This should get me the that div element right  ? Can you help me what should be the proper query ?

Comment: I think I got to know why its not working. The html code after table is dynamically loaded by dijitToolbar class and not present exclusively in my html file.
Even though my query is same as the one you executed ( in js file), the query is returning null to me and hence the div element is not getting inserted. I am not sure what do do next

Comment: I am not getting the reference of the div before which I need to add a new div. Thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should not place Javascript or CSS within the HTML code. It makes the code ureadable and unmaintanable (if that is a word). You should separete your files toy makes your life easier.

To place an element before another element you should use domConstruct, which apparently you did, but you have to call all function AFTER a page haw finished loading.

When you write javascript code and you just inject it in the HTML code sometimes the code loads way before the actual page and the element you are looking for. To solve this problem you can use [dojo ready](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/ready.html#dojo-ready) and from within call / register any other function.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have not mixed the code. The first part of the code is present in a separate html file and the second part of the code is present in another js file.

The html loads first right ? Only after that JS loads if my understanding is right !

Comment: That is not the case as I came to understand ... To make sure you this is the case you have to use dojo.ready.

Comment: I have not yet. I am not sure of the syntax. Looking through it

Comment: I am not getting the reference of the div before which I need to add a new div. Thats the problem

Answer (score 0):

Which version of dojo are you using? 
I think [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/ready.html) is the right thing you should do if you are using dojo 1.7 and above it's the dojo/ready module. And there is also [dojo/domReady!](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/domReady.html) which you could use if I'm not totally wrong.